# Execution flow using next()

Tags: javascript, express, routes, middleware

I am new to express and have a question about mechanics of next() function.

1. Am I correct that once next() is called it immediately triggers execution of app.get, whilst everything below next() will be executed asynchronously?
2. If so, why 'Am I executed?' is not printed to console once I put big delay in setTimeout()?

Please explain execution flow in the code below.

```
app.param('seriesId', (req, res, next) => {
  ... // Check for presence of series
  console.log('I am executed');
  next();
  setTimeout(() => {console.log('Am I executed?')}, 1000); // Prints for 100, does not print for 1000
});

app.get('/:seriesId', (req, res, next) => {
  ... // Call to db to get series object
  res.status(200).json({series: series});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `next()` will handle control over to the next middleware in the pipe. In your example, this would be the `app.get`.

However, the method does not behave like a `return` statement, so any code you put after, will get executed too.

Given the example below, if you would start the server and navigate to http://localhost:1337/foo, the log statements would be:

1. well here we are
2. executing the get

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.param('param',(req, res, next) => {
    next();
    setTimeout(() => console.log('well here we are'), 1000);
});

app.get('/:param', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('executing the get');
        res.status(200).send();
    }, 2000);
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log('app started at http://localhost:1337');
```

### Branching in middleware

A good practice to avoid confusion, is to make sure calls to `next()` are placed at the end of your execution. For example, don't do this:

```js
if(aCondition) {
    next()
}
next(new Error('Condition was false'));
```

But do:

```js
if(aCondition) {
    next()
} else {
    next(new Error('Condition was false'));
}
```

Alternatively, what I do is always return `next()` calls, to avoid middleware from executing any further code.

### Executing async code in middleware

And a final remark: if you need to execute asynchronous code in your middleware, then only call `next()` once this code has finished executing.

Don't do:

```js
loadUserFromDB()
    .then(u => req.user = u);
next();
```

But do:

```js
loadUserFromDB()
    .then(u => {
         req.user = u;
         next();
    });
```

Comment: Everything is clear - thx. Just the last question, in my case - if I use `setTimeout()` in `app.param` with delay 1000, and do not use it in `app.get`, why then the statement in `setTimeout(..., 1000)` is not printed to the console? If I put 100, everything works fine.

Comment: @smokedsalmon hard to tell with the given code. A possible explanation is that the execution instance is shut down after one second. So setting the timeout to 100 falls within that limit. This might occur when you're running your code on AWS Lambda or a similar cloud based solution.

Comment: I used localhost and tried to print out these statements while running tests (mocha). My best guess is that when I set delay to 1000, another test request (post/put) runs before this callback in `setTimeout()` gets executed, thereby, shutting down the previous execution.

Comment: @smokedsalmon that's a reasonable explanation yes, the previous execution would be killed when the next test runs.